# Heroku showing json data rather than UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

My heroku app is showing my json data from an api call in my backend rather than my frontend UI. I think this is happening because I have two "/" routes- one in my frontend router and one in my `app.get("/", async (req, res)` call in the backend. I'm not sure how to fix this though, because the app won't work if I don't have a backend index route, but it will also not know what to display on my homepage in the front end if I don't have an index route. How do I fix this issue? Here is my code:

App.js:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <>

      <NavBar />

      <div className="container">
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/reddit" element={<Reddit />} />
            <Route path="/news" element={<News />} />
          </Routes>
      </div>
  </>
  );
```

fetch calls in each separate React page:
`fetch('https://herokuappname.com/newsarticles')`, `fetch('https://herokuappname.com/redditapi')`, `fetch('https://herokuappname.com/)`

backend.js:

```js
const PORT = Number(process.env["PORT"]) || 8000 
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const {TwitterApi} = require('twitter-api-v2')
const axios = require('axios')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
require('dotenv').config()
const snoowrap = require('snoowrap')

const app = express()
app.use(cors())


app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    const client = new TwitterApi(process.env.twt_bearer_token)

    const trendsInternational = await client.v1.trendsByPlace(1);

    const trendList = []

    for (const {trends} of trendsInternational) {
        for (const trend of trends) {
            trendList.push({
                name: trend.name,
                url: trend.url
            })
        }
    }

    res.json(trendList)
})

app.get('/redditapi', async (req, res) => {
    const r = new snoowrap({
        userAgent: process.env.user_agent,
        clientId: process.env.client_id,
        clientSecret: process.env.client_secret,
        refreshToken: process.env.refresh_token
    })

    topPosts = []
    
    ;(await r.getHot()).forEach(post => {
        topPosts.push({
            title: post.title,
            url: post.url
        })
    })
    
    res.json(topPosts);

})

app.get('/newsarticles', async (req, res) => {
    const news_url = 'https://www.theguardian.com/international'

    axios(news_url)
    .then(response => {
        const html = response.data;
        const $ = cheerio.load(html);
        const articles = [];
        const values = new Set();

        $('.fc-item__title', html).each(function () { //<-- cannot be a function expression

            const title = $(this).text().trim();
            const url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');

            if (!values.has(url)) {

              values.add(url);

              articles.push({
                  title,
                  url
              });
            }  
        })
        res.json(articles)
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))


})

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`))
```

package.json scripts:

```js
"scripts": {
    "start:backend": "nodemon backend.js",
    "start:frontend": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "concurrently \"react-scripts start\" \"nodemon backend.js\"",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```

Comment: One thing: I think your `path="/"` route should go last. I would also put the express route `\` last too. And do you have [a procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) in your root folder?

Comment: yes I do have a procfile in my root folder @Andy